# How to align an image and a navbar inside a container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I am not able to align the logo and the nav bar inside the container div. The navigation bar is always below the level of the image logo. I have tried some html align attributes but it did not fix the issue. I am using bootstrap CSS, so should I change something in there ?

```
<header>
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">

            <!--company logo and slogan-->
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" />

            <!--button for responsive navigation-->
            ...

            <!--Nav bar-->
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">        
              <ul class="nav pull-right" >
                ...
              </ul>
                            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `float`s?  Maybe have the image `float:left;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to float left your img and your div tag as follow :

```
<header>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container" style="overflow: auto; ">

                <!--company logo and slogan-->
                <img src="img/logo.png" style="float: left; " alt="logo" />

                <!--Nav bar-->
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse" style="float: left; ">        
                  <ul class="nav pull-right" >
                    ...
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

That should make them show at the same level.

Comment: `overflow: auto` is applied to the container since it only contains uncleared, floating elements. Anything other than `overflow: visible` will ensure your containing element takes into account its floated elements when calculating its dimension.